# Shape appears different in edit mode, object mode and render

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to animate a figure to jump and the animation runs fine when I play it in timeline but when I render image/animation, it also shows the initial T-pose figure that I started with:
[image: in render image]
what i found is that in the edit mode the shape of the figure is still in the initial t-pose and the armature seems disconnected from the object

**in edit mode:**
[image: in edit mode]
whereas in the object mode the armature and body are connected and not in t-pose

**in object mode:**
[image: in object mode]

is it because I had not applied the armature modifier before making the animation?

Comment: When you hop into *Edit* mode then the mesh is automatically put in rest position. That's the reason why it looks different in *Object*  mode (pose position) and *Edit* mode (=rest position). You can switch the position in the *Object Data Properties* of the armature ("green running man" icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have a duplicate of your object in you scene. The one  named tpose_human_body. I see you have it hidden but blender still renders it. If you want it to not be rendered move it into a new collection and disable the collection from the view layer by unchecking the tickbox near it.

There was a simpler way to disable render for objects before but it has changed and I don't know how to do it in `2.8`.

**EDIT**

In `2.7`'s Outliner, after each Object's name there was the Restriction Toggles button :

[image]

The right most button (the one that looks like a camera) is the one used for disabling/enabling an object for render.

In `2.8`+, one might think that those buttons were gone but they are just hidden. In the Outliner's header, there is a `Filter` dropdown :

[image]

If you click on this you will see a section called `Restriction Toggles` :

[image]

You'll find the one that you're looking for there : [image]

If you enable it, you should see it in the Outliner now :

[image]

Clicking on it will toggle between visible and invisible in renders.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct there was an extra object in my collection that I had hidden which was standing in t-pose though it is not the tpose_human_body object which is another plane as image that I imported which also shows in the render if in the camera's area even when hidden. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I helped.